# Improving Ajax auto-complete to return better result

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am using ajax & php to fetch elements that matches keys(letters) entered by user with elements resembling the database.

for e.g database contain manufacturer names as:

```
Hydfloo, Rexflex, Easton, Vickters, EVER GUSH, Thomas Hydraulics, AVT Pumps
```

and say for example user has entered the letter "H" into the input box. Then I only receive Hydfloo as return and not Thomas Hydraulics along with it. Also if "p" is typed I wd expect to see "AVT Pumps". What changes do I need to make to my php in order to be able to have all the values returned that matches either the first or even the second word of the manufacturer name.

**PHP code**

```
 <?php
    require('../config/connection.php');

    if(!$dbc) {

        echo 'Could not connect to the database.';
    } else {

if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
    $queryString = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['queryString']);

    if(strlen($queryString) >0) {

  $query = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT distinct name FROM prdct_subcat WHERE name LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10");
  echo '<ul>';

  while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

  echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.addslashes($result['name']).'\');">'.$result['name'].'</li>';
            }
        echo '</ul>';


            } 
        } 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression instead of `LIKE`, so you can match a word boundary anywhere in the value.

Change

```
WHERE name LIKE '$queryString%'
```

to:

```
WHERE name REGEXP '[[:<:]]$queryString'
```

in the SQL.

Comment: @Barmer sorry mate do I need to write something like
"SELECT distinct name FROM prdct_subcat WHERE name REGEX '[[:<:]]$queryString' LIMIT 10"  this instead you mean

Comment: Yes but it doesn't return anything

Comment: I had a typo. You should check the return value and print `mysql_error()` when the query fails, so you can see this.

Comment: @barmer you forgot about parenthesis in your code. Please amend it & I will accept your answer :)

Comment: Parentheses aren't needed in this, nothing is being grouped.

Comment: Yeah you r right. Looks like I was doing a typo. Thanks for the answer mate.